# Transpose image in photoshop (without flip)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I transpose this initial image

[image]

to this final image in photoshop ?

[image]

I've tried in vain using grids (and copy/paste one by one), but all of that is going approximate and is not precise. And flipping inverts the numbers laterally.

Thanks.

[Edit]
It is strange that people started with solutions (or rather lack of it) and started giving negative points. More context: I paid for this poster https://gum.co/Prime-Climb-Hundreds-Chart and my little kid is used to reading numbers in a transposed way. The distance between the circles is uneven. So, I could not find a way to have different grid spacing  vertically and horizontally. Finally, I managed it. I selected each row, free transformed it by 90 degrees. Then, took each circle and then rotated it by 90 degrees. Repeated manual work, but it works.

Comment: Why aren't grids precise? Or better yet, why can't you type in new numbers?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I get the gist of it, but why is manually doing it not working? PS has align options in the move tool, which you could use to rearrange them in a few minutes. One way would be to use [data sets and variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html), so you'd just need to change the values, without having to do any aligning in PS. But depending on what you are doing, it might be a bit unnecessarily complicated. If you only need to change the order once, you might be better off doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose a pixels and data elements in a picture, but since the picture consists of pixels and not individual collections of pixels or vector shapes then the transpose would not look like your result.

No the computer can not arbitrarily know what should be part of a cell and what should not be. However if you can define the cell sizes then a script could be made to do this. But this is clearly outside the intended purpose of Phothoshop so I am not going to dwell much on the situation. Wouldn't it be easier to transpose the source.

The only easy way is to cut the image into squares and move the squares* about. No theres no builtin function to do this. Especially since your image is not even. The a computer can not use judgement to decide why grid 8 is bigger than grid 6. So inaccuracy is a builtin feature of your source.

*In this particular case its possible to make a slight optimization, however this does not extend to all pictures. Since the background is so easily selected you can in fact isolate each sub image exactly to its own layer and then align snap them. Though its more work than redrawing the image to begin with.

Comment: I'd advocate the use of the Text tool would be easier than splicing and moving parts of the image at all